# Div doesnt load with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with div loading/fading.. This is my html.

```
<div id="email_response">
<div id="email_loader">
    <img src="/img/ajax_load.gif.pagespeed.ce.sBYFmTTK7I.gif">
</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
    $("#email_loader").html("<img src='http://example.com/img/ajax_load.gif' />");

    $("#email_response").fadeIn(500);
$.get("http://example.com/inc_appdl_main_api.php", {
        to : to,
        app_id : FA.appID
    }, function(data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
                         $("#email_loader").html(data);
             $("#email_response").delay(1000).fadeOut(500);   
        }

    });
         setTimeout ( "FA.iframeClose()", 2000 );
```

The div email_response , should load/fadeIn for half a second..then the response should be obtained from jquery ..and then a the end an iframe that contains all the html markup should close..

Everything works apart from the code inside the get success function.. 
I know that the success function is actually triggered..cause the server (php) code, does what it does!!!

Whats the problem? I dont see the response fading out..
The code inside the success function doesnt work :(

```
if (data.length > 0) {
                     $("#email_loader").html(data);
             $("#email_response").delay(1000).fadeOut(500);   
        }
```

UPDATE:
THIS IS WHAT I GET IN THE CONSOLE. AFTER THE GET FUNCTION IS TRIGGERED.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/inc_appdl_main_api.php?to=makovetskiyd%40yahoo.co.uk&app_id=81. Origin http://api.example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

The html markup and javascript is in an iframe which has another site on it..

Comment: how can I debug it.. only with a function of error()... but I dont see in the documentation that there is such a function for $.get().. is everything else right?!?

Comment: You are missing a closing `</div>` tag for #email_response. Was this a copy & paste error?

Comment: you can see it from the console, you will see  the response detailed

Comment: Could you elaborate on `I know that the success function is actually triggered..cause the server (php) code, does what it does!!!`. When you have an `alert()` inside your success handler, will it show?

Comment: **Never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Comment: I've changed the domain name in your question to "example.com". Swearing is inappropriate on SO, and the domain name itself was not central to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin. You are accessing something  out of your domain? [cross-domain-requests-with-jquery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/), [cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html)