# Domain, subdomain requests error

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, iframe

I have my iframe such as this:

```
<iframe src="http://api.example.com/html/31" id="fa-iframe" scrolling="No" frameborder="0" style="height: 513px; width: 597px; "></iframe>
```

and a javascript like this:

```
$.get("/inc_appdl_main.php", { id=args },function(data) {});
```

The website is `http://example.com` ...

I want to reach this file in my directory inc_appdl_main.php.

However, when I do the request,.. the internet doesnt allow me cause it interprets:

`http://example.com` 
 and

```
http://api.example.com
```

as two seperates domains..although both are the same sites..with a different url. api is simply a folder that the get request gets to.

I have two options to use in my get. 
Either..

```
.get(" http://api.example.com/inc_appdl_main.php", { id=args },function(data) {});
```

which will give me "404"

or

```
 .get(" http://example.com/inc_appdl_main.php", { id=args },function(data) {});
```

which will give me an error that I cant post across domains

Although the site is the same site, the url is different.. and I need to get to this file..

```
inc_appdl_main which sits on the same root directory...is there a way?
```

Comment: I've changed the domain name in your question to "example.com". Swearing is inappropriate on SO, and the domain name itself was not central to the question.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205288/div-doesnt-load-with-jquery

Comment: very true Crowder.. I work in a porn firm..what can i do?

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd: First, use example.com as your domain.  Second, you can send us samples.  As long as you're not an actor but a key grip.  Wait, that still sounds bad.  Okay, scratch the sample part.  But keep the links to your website out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of possible solutions:

1. Configure your server so that it can accept the request for `http://api.example.com/inc_appdl_main.php`, processing it as though it were `http://example.com/inc_appdl_main.php"`. This is probably the easiest, as you're in control of the server.
2. If the response from `api.example.com` is an HTML page, add JavaScript to it to set [`document.domain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.domain) to `example.com`.
3. Require that your users use a [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) (CORS) [compatible browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors) and reply to the CORS preflight requests and such on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Set the header() in inc_appdl_main.php to allow cross origin requests

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```